# What is a good way to pan view a little more up when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a activity that has the "adjustPan" option set and it pans my view up just fine when a EditText receives focus and the soft keyboard is shown, but my problem is that there are UI elements below my EditText that needs to be visible also when the keyboard is shown and it is not on smaller screens. Can I some how tell the view to always pan so that those UI elements are visible by linking them to the EditText or something, or do I have to take control of the panning manually and calculate height and all, or what is the good solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is you can use ViewTreeObserver to pan your content l'il bit more.
        I did this is my app.

```
    int edtHeight = 0;

    // llContent is the Viewgroup layout which is inside a ScrollView.
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver1 = llContent.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            // Here edtHeight will get the height of edittext as i wanted my view to scroll that much bit more
            edtHeight = edtTemprature.getHeight();

            ViewTreeObserver obs = llContent.getViewTreeObserver();

            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
 });

//llMain is the parent View Group of my XML layout 
    llMain.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                // r will be populated with the coordinates of your view
                // that area still visible.
                llMain.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                int heightDiff = llMain.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                if (heightDiff > 100)
                { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    if(edtTemprature.hasFocus()){
                        llContent.scrollTo(0, (int) (edtHeight * 1.5));
                    }else{
                        llContent.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    llContent.scrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes that was my only idea also, was hoping there was a smarter way

Comment: I tried to find out better way too but ended up using this @Neigaard

Answer (score -2):

Use stateHidden in Android manifestfile which class you need ..

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

or else,

In Activity,

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

Comment: No, I do want the keyboard but I want some control over how far/long it pans my view

Comment: In My Program, I am using stateHidden and also  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for pad the edit text. It's working fine ..

Comment: That is just all wrong, stateHidden indicates to the activity that the soft keyboard should not be displayed pr. default (you have to manually set focus to display it), it does absolutely nothing to panning length or anything else - it is a wrong answer.